# I can't get x and y coordinate of movement in flutter container

Tags: flutter, dart

> I want to get the x and y coordinates as long as my finger travels inside the container.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final key = GlobalKey();
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  double X_Position = 0.00;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  double Y_Position = 0.00;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: (details) {
          RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          setState(() {
            X_Position = position.dx;
            Y_Position = position.dy;
          });
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          setState(() {
            X_Position = position.dx;
            Y_Position = position.dy;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> In the above code, I want to get the x and y coordinates according to the movement of my finger inside the container. But I am getting the following error. can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer just using `DragUpdateDetails` that comes from `onPanUpdate`.

```dart
body: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  onPanStart: (details) {
    Offset position = details.localPosition;
    setState(() {
      X_Position = position.dx;
      Y_Position = position.dy;
    });
  },
  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
    Offset position = details.localPosition;
    setState(() {
      X_Position = position.dx;
      Y_Position = position.dy;
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You must give the key to the container as a parameter

Container(
key: key,
),

Answer (score 1):

The key isn't attached to any widget:

Attach it like so:

```
Container(
  key: key,
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
     border: Border.all(
       color: Colors.black,
       width: 2,
     ),
   ),
)
```

**EDIT**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: (details) {
          RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          setState(() {
            X_Position = position.dx;
            Y_Position = position.dy;
          });
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          setState(() {
            X_Position = position.dx;
            Y_Position = position.dy;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This code above will always have the Container at Offset(0,0) that's why the values of `X_Position` and `Y_Position` is always 0.

To see changes, put the `Container` in a `Center`

Like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: (details) {
          RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          setState(() {
            X_Position = position.dx;
            Y_Position = position.dy;
          });
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          Offset position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
          setState(() {
            X_Position = position.dx;
            Y_Position = position.dy;
          });
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did what you said, problem solved. But x and y values are always returning 0. How can i fix it.

Comment: The `Container` is placed on Offset(0,0)...Do you want to be able to drag the Container around add see the offset change?

Comment: now I want to get the x and y coordinates of the container on the screen. But x and y always return zero.

Comment: Check the edit @ahmetçıtır

Comment: I did as you edited but it still returns zero with X_position and Y_position value.

Comment: Where are you checking for the updated values?
Can you try `print("X position is $X_Position");` in `onPanStart` after the `setState`?

Comment: Try printing details.localPosition.dx;